# Extracting Nth fields from a record

Tags: sql

I´m looking for any way to extract data like below in SQL:

```
"Develop_Server   Linux15a1   /home   5152384   2136036   2754616      44"
"Homolog_Server   Linux37a9   /var   5152384   2136036   2754616      57"
"Produc_Server    Linux43a5   /usr   5152384   2136036   2754616      98"
"Produc_Server    Linux23a0   /sys   5152384   2136036   2754616      43"

select first field as Server, second field as Server_name, third field as FS,
fourth field as fs_width, fifth field as FS_Used, sisxth field as FS_available, 
seventh field as Perc_Usage
(Each row is a record)
Please help me.
Thanks.
```

Comment: Just use the column names.  Please edit your question and post the table layout.

Comment: What rdbms are you using? You cannot access columns by ordinal position (easily). Why don't you know the names?

Comment: I'd edit this file with ultraedit or notepad++, replace double blank space with one blank space a few times after no match found. Then import it to a table

Comment: If this is a text file that you are importing, look for a way to make it delimited before you talk to your database.

Comment: I can insert a pipe between each recor, like this:   "Develop_Server|Linux15a1|/home|5152384|2136036|2754616|44"

Comment: Just what I've said before. A single blank space act as a delimiter. You can replace it for a tab or a pipe |, but I don't recommend a hyphen because it my be used in a name

Comment: Bulk Import and Export of Data (SQL Server) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175937.aspx

Comment: These data are populated in a monitoring Syslog server, and I need use T-sql to extract the data.

Comment: sorry, do you have this as one field records in a SQL Server Table?

Comment: Yes, they are one field records (separated by spaces)

Comment: Why this task is so difficult in Sql ? In Unix shell this is so easy...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your row is fixed length.  You can do something like this:

```
select substr(row, 1, 19) as Server,
       substr(row, 20, 10) as Server_name, 
       . . .
```

You will need to figure out what the right lengths and offsets are.

Most databases support either `substr()` or `substring()`.

You might also want to remove spaces.  Most databases support either `trim()` or `rtrim()` and `ltrim()`.

Comment: We have hundreds File systems, and unfortunately they aren´t fixed length.

Answer (score 0):

First, create destination table:

```
CREATE TABLE FinalTable
([Server] varchar(50), 
[Server_name] varchar(50), 
[FS] varchar(50), 
[fs_width] varchar(50), 
[FS_Used] varchar(50), 
[FS_available] varchar(50), 
[Perc_Usage] varchar(50))
;
```

Using a cursor and dynamic sql, row by row

```
declare @sql varchar(max)
declare @onlyField varchar(max)

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR  
SELECT onlyField from logTable 

OPEN db_cursor   
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @onlyField   

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN   
       SET @sql = 'insert into FinalTable select '''+REPLACE(@onlyField,'|',''',''')+''''

        EXEC (@sql)   

       FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @onlyField   
END   

CLOSE db_cursor   
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

Comment: Assuming your table is called `logTable` and have an only field `onlyField` and delimited by a pipe `|`

Comment: @user1658549 have you tried this answer? if it works for you, could you formally accept it? http://stackoverflow.com/tour